# Multiple params using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having some weird problem passing multiple parameters using `ui-router`

My `ui-sref` looks like this:

```
ui-sref="app.bins.view({binId:{{gridDisplayItem.id}},allowUpload:'{{gridDisplayItem.user_upload}}'})"
```

if I inspect the element, I see something like:

```
<a ui-sref="app.bins.view({binId:3,allowUpload:'No'})" href="#/app/bins/view/3">
  <i class="fa fa-folder-open" style="font-size:18px;color:green"></i>
</a>
```

so the correct value is being passed.

When I navigate to `app.bins.view` and I do a `console.log($stateParams.binId);` it shows `3`.

If I do a `console.log($stateParams.allowUpload);` I get `undefined`.

If I do a `console.log($stateParams);` I get `Object {binId: "3"}`

According to the docs, I am doing this correctly: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use 'No'...otherwise it is looking for the variable No...

Comment: I am still getting `undefined` with quotes around the value. Edited my post to reflect the single quotes

Comment: did you declare both of your params in your ui-route?

Comment: remove the `href` attribute from your link

Comment: more detailed information about your situation:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

Comment: @friedi the `href` is generated from the `ui-sref`

Comment: @beauXjames what if I don't want that param in the address bar? Should I use another means of getting that variable rather than `stateParams`?

Comment: I guess the question then is what you are wanting these params sent to your ui-router for...what do you need 'allowUpload' param in the ui-router for? seems like something you could use a call to your controller then in the controller manage the view switch

Comment: I was thinking I can just send this param to the next view and controller and access it through stateParams but it looks like that isn't the way I should go. In my `app/bins/view/:binId` view/controller I need access to the `allowUpload` value to basically hide the upload field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, the information in the ui-router documentation (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) to understand is the following

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
   url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
   }
}).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
   url: '/item/:itemId', 
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId //*** Watch Out! DOESN'T EXIST!! ***//
      $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
   }
})
```

You must be sure to declare your parameters in the configuration of the provider.

If the purpose of your 'allowUpload' parameter is what I think it is, there should be no reason you cannot use an ng-click event on your href to have a function called in your controller that then uses  the $state.go() method to manage the view change. Just pass in the variable to the controller.

Comment: I am defining my controllers in the config like `controller: 'ViewBinController'` but I understand this and I think using an ng-click coupled with the $state.go will work great, thank you

Comment: I'm still trying to get it to work, lol don't worry I won't leave ya hangin

Comment: I've got this pattern in lots of places...update your question is you're stuck...